# c++ template type pack specialization for tuple

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, variadic-templates, template-specialization

When trying to implement a tuple type i run into the problem an empty tuple.
This is the type structure i used:

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
struct Tuple : public Tuple<Ts...> {};

template <class T>
struct Tuple {};
```

As soon as i try to add an overload for no type the compiler complains: `Too few template arguments for class template 'Tuple'`:

```
template <> struct Tuple<> {};
```

I guess it's because the Tuple type was declared with at least one provided type at first and the compiler can't overload the same type with a different set of template parameters, but i wonder how i could solve this problem without completely restructuring my code.
My first idea was to define the tuple like `template <class... Ts> struct Tuple {};` first and than add the other overloads, but the compiler than complains for to much template arguments.

Comment: your first idea was actually right. If you have a question about code it is better to include a [mcve] and the error message. My answer is bascially just what you say, but I don't know what error you have in the code when you tried

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You are right, i forgot to add the types to the following declarations because they specialize the tuple after adding the `template <class...Ts> struct Tuple {};` before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template expects at least one parameter. You can change it like this to allow zero or more:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct Tuple;

template <>
struct Tuple<> {};

template <class T,class... Ts>
struct Tuple<T,Ts...> : public Tuple<Ts...> {};

int main()
{
    Tuple<int,int,double> t;
}
```